# R dataframe: how to "populate" missing data in df1 using df2

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, merge, na

I am trying to populate the missing values of df1 with  df2.
Whenever there is a valid value for the same cell in both df, I need to keep the value as in df1.
If there is a column in df2 that is not present in df1, this new column (z) has to be added to df1.

This would be a simple example:

```
id <- c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x <- c (10, NA, 20, 50, 70)
y <- c (3, 5, NA, 6, 9)
df1 <- data.frame(id, x, y)

id <- c ( 2, 3, 5)
x <- c (10, NA, NA)
z <- c (NA, 6, 7)
df2 <- data.frame(id, x, z)
```

I would like to obtain "df3":

```
id  x y  z
1  1 10 3 NA
2  2 10 5 NA
3  3 20 6  6
4  4 50 6 NA
5  5 70 9  7
```

I tried several "merge" options that didn't work.

Comment: @Jaume I have a doubt.  Suppose one of the data have more columns than the other, what will be the expected output?  Are you assuming that both data have the same number of columns (except difference in column names) i.e. add two more columns in 'df1' `df1$v <- c(2, 5, NA, NA, 4);
df1$u <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2)`

Comment: @akrun: df1 is the dataframe to be completed with df2, so if there are columns present in df2 that are not in df1, these need to be added. If there are more columns in df1, they stay in the final df as they are. Also, I am assuming that column names are the same in both dataframes. tidyverse is great but any other option works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A '`merge`' option after several extract and replace steps could be

```
idx <- is.na(df1[df2$id,])
df1[df2$id,][idx] <- df2[idx]
out <- merge(df1, df2[, c("id", "z")], by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

Result

```
out
#  id  x y  z
#1  1 10 3 NA
#2  2 10 5 NA
#3  3 20 6  6
#4  4 50 6 NA
#5  5 70 9  7
```